# Equivalent in Pandas of R data.table code : df[, new_column := column2/(1:.N), by=(column1)]

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the pandas equivalent of the following R data.table line.

```
df[, new_column := column2/(1:.N), by=(column1)]
```

I want to create a new column in Pandas. df with the average of the values of column2 grouped by column1. The values of the new column have to be different. As you go through the instances of the group the average changes.

For example, if a group in column1 has a size of 15:

```
value_column2 / 1

value_column2 / 2

.....

.....

value_column2 / 15
```

I have reached this point:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column2'].groupby(df['column1']).transform('size')
```

..or the same:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('column1')['column2'].transform('size')
```

I get a new column with the size of the groups. I do not know if what I'm looking for can be related to this.

Comment: Is there no `mean` function. Just asking. Not a pythoner. Only use R.  Seems more likely to deliver what was desired than using `size`.

Comment: Can you add a sample DataFrame with your desired output?

Comment: From the bit you added here, you might be looking for `df['col2'] / df.groupby('col1')['col2'].cumcount()`

Comment: I already solved my doubt. Thank you ayhan for your answer. The cumcount () function has been very helpful.
I'm sorry for my English and for the writing in the forum. It's the first time I post a question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ayhan's help I have already got the answer I needed.

The equivalent in Pandas to this R data.table code:

```
df[, new_column := column2/(1:.N), by=(column1)]
```

is:

```
df["new_column"] = (df['column2']) / (df.groupby('column1')['column2'].cumcount()+1)
```